# How can I convert this text to desired array format and export in csv?

Tags: php, data-extraction, pdftotext

I have this text extracted from pdf using `pdftotext` tool

Please find below text structure

```
stage    title1    title2  title3  title4
I        value1    value2  value3  
II                         value5  value6

stage    Other1      Other2     Other3     Other4
I        otherval1   otherval2  otherval3  otherval4
```

Now I want to export this text in CSV format using appropriate columns and headers this way or build an array this way

```
[
  "category" => "title1",
  "score"    => "value1",
],
[
  "category" => "title2",
  "score"    => "value2",
],
[
  "category" => "title3",
  "score"    => "value3"
],
// unable to to do this
[
  "category" => "title3",
  "score"    => "value5"
],
[
  "category" => "title4",
  "score"    => "value6",
],

.
.
// so on
```

**Now the problem is**

- Column values in I stage and II stage are optional, but any one of
  the rows will contain at least one value for each column
- Stage II row is optional, may exist or not
- If stage II row exists then at least one column value exists in the
  row

**The problem I am facing is how can I map**

- value5 to title3
- value6 to titl4

**Here is my parser code (PHP)**

```
$rows = explode("\n", $pdfExtractedText);
$rows = array_values(array_filter($rows));

$categories = array_values(array_filter(explode(" ", $rows[7])));
$stage1Scores = array_values(array_filter(explode(" ", $rows[8])));
$stage2Scores = array_values(array_filter(explode(" ", $rows[9])));
var_dump($categories);
var_dump($stage1Scores);
var_dump($stage2Scores);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
// categories
array:13 [
  0 => "stage"
  1 => "title1"
  2 => "title2"
  3 => "title3"
  4 => "title4"
]

//values - Index preserved so that I can map with categories
array:14 [
  0 => "I"
  1 => "value1"
  2 => "value2"
  3 => "value3"
  4 => "value4"
]

// index not preserved :(
array:2 [
  0 => "II"
  1 => "value5",
  2 => "value6"
]
```

Comment: Your wanting a way to parse the output to an array then?

Comment: or are you just wanting to push it to a csv format?

Comment: @Hudson CSV would also do if it preserves the desired header

Comment: I've answered below, if you need any changes, just comment underneath the answer and i'll correct anything.

Answer (score 0):

Then try this,

```
$csv = "";

$csv .= implode("," , $categories) . PHP_EOL; 
$csv .= implode("," , $stage1scores) . PHP_EOL;
$csv .= implode("," , $stage2scores) . PHP_EOL;
```

Then write it to a file.

Comment: wont you think this will print `value5` under `title1` ? while I need `value5` under `title3`

Comment: Have you mapped the keys to the values?

Comment: if not autopopulate, put a null value in place of the empty columns

Comment: I am looking solution for that problem ,I am unable to map keys with values correctly

Comment: Please check my php parser code and extracted text structure

Comment: validate it then, check the count of each row, make a max column  count and check the length, if not they is some format problems. You can further diagnose from there.

Comment: for instance, `if(count($stage1scores) < 5)){ //not a valid row //adapt script }`

Comment: Theres no way I can count column all that I am getting in extracted text  is space

Comment: I'd personally create a class to parse the output, instead of a few array_filters. have the class handle it line by line. and validate, you should try splitting on whitespace via `preg_split`.

Comment: There are thousand of tabular data in this structure I cant just write logic for each table , this is just a single table example

Comment: is there anything I can achieve it dynamically?

Comment: Yes, have a class, with multiple rules , it can have an algorithm for each type of row

Comment: can you provide logic for the example I have provided in question :P to map `value5` to `title3`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173892/discussion-between-reverbnation-and-hudson).